# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::removeChild() in /var/www/html/gatewayFromFroentEnd/server.php on line 68

Tags: php, xml

I want to delete xml element node by php if attribute I am sending is
matched by button, getting

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMNodeList::removeChild() in /var/www/html/gatewayFromFroentEnd/server.php on line 68
```

This line is 68 which is not working:
`$gatewayNameArray1->removeChild($gatewayNameArray1);`

My code is

```
if(isset($_POST['removeGateway'])){
    removeGatewayRow();
}

function removeGatewayRow(){
    echo "good morning";
    echo "<br>";
    $dom1 = new DOMDocument();
    $dom1->load('gateways.xml') or die("unable to open gateway.xml<br>");
    $gatewayNameArray1 = $dom1->getElementsByTagName('gateway');
    //print_r($gatewayNameArray1->getAttribute('name'));

    foreach ($gatewayNameArray1 as $values){
        $gatewayName = $values->getAttribute('name');

        print_r($gatewayName);
        echo "<br>";

        foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
            echo "<br> key:value -->";
            echo $key .":".$value;
            echo "--------------"; 
            if ($key=="removeGateway"){
                if ($value==$gatewayName){
                    echo "+++$value:$gatewayName+++ gatewayName matched";

                    $gatewayNameArray1->removeChild($gatewayNameArray1);
                    $dom1->save("gateways.xml");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's telling you that the class does not have the method. You probably wanted to use [this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php), which is a method of `DOMNode`, not `DOMNodeList`, which your object is.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what exactly do you want to do here? Do you want to delete `$gatewayNameArray1`? That's an array! Or do you want to delete each `$values` if it matches? Also why are you deleting from `$gatewayNameArray1`? Shouldn't you delete from `$dom1` ?

Comment: sir i have list of gateway name in frontend, and i am sending that name by a button in post request, so if gateway name get matched in xml file, that node should be deleted sir, please can you help